# Simple JQuery validation

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, validation

Just after a check to make sure one hidden field is not empty.

```
if($('#cal_startdate').val('')) {
        alert('Please select a start date') }
        else { form.submit }
```

That isn't quite right. I'd rather it was an onsubmit action.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

EDIT

Comment: do u have any html that goes with this js?

Comment: i repeat: `do u have any html that goes with this js? – Neal 28 secs ago`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to attach the validation to the `submit()` event handler. If data is valid, return true - else, return false.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if ($('#cal_startdate').val().length==0){
        alert('Please Enter Start Date');
        return(false);
    }
    return(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
  if($('#cal_startdate').val() == ""){
    alert('Please select a start date');
    return false; // To avoid the submit (error)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    if($("#cal_startdate").val() === ""){
        alert("Please select a start date");
        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware, here you are using `val()` as a setter. Effectively, calling `<selection>.val('')` will set your input to something empty. What you want to do is the following:

```
if($('#cal_startdate').val() === '')
  alert('Please select a start date');
else
  form.submit();
```

That should work now

Comment: Isn't `if ($('#cal_startdate').val().length==0){...}` more widely accepted?